# multi variable function, is it a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

By definition one element of the domain have at most is graphed to one codomain element to be defined as a function.

Is the case of a general $y=f(x)$ if a given $x=a$ line cuts the graph twice, $y=f(x)$ is not a function.

is there a "function" with 2 variables which is not a function?

Comment: What is a function of what ? By the way, you show an implicit equation, not a parametric one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust edited, for more clarity

Comment: This doesn't add clarity, on the opposite. What is a function of what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, I am trying to understand if we can define a "rule" with 2 variables which is not a function?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ does not define $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$, just like $x^2+y^2=1$ does not define $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets. A relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ is called a function from $A$ to $B$, only if $(a,b)\in R \land (a,b^\prime)\in R$ implies $b=b^\prime$.

Now to your example with the circle (to make things easier, I use a circle that is centered in the origin of the coordinate system and has radius 1):

- The relation $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R \mid x^2+y^2=1\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is *not* a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (when trying to map the $x$-value to the $y$-value).
- However, you can (for example) define a function $f^+$ with $f^+(x):=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ that gives you the positive $y$-values and a function $f^-$ with $f^-(x):=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ that gives you the negative $y$-values. So each function describes a semicircle.
- It is also possible to describe a circle by a parameterized function. For example, you can use the angle as parameter and define a function from $[0,2\pi)$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: But in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$ $x^2+y^2=1$ is a function, because every set of (x,y) is mapped to just one value of $z$?

Comment: Yes, that would be a function. Maybe not the best way of representing a circle, but it's a function.

Answer (score 2):

You correctly realized that the circle is not the *graph* of a function.

The way you worded your question is a little confusing, but that's not surprising since you were confused - it does not make sense to ask whether the circle "is" a function.

(You just edited your question so that this answer no longer matches the original. I will leave it up for a while - perhaps it will help you.)